# How do I get an anchor # link to work from a different page with a fixed header?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I want to link content in the middle of a page. I'm using an anchor tag link but it only works correctly if i'm already on the page clicking it. I needed to hight adjust the link because of a fixed header on the page. If I link it on an external page it does not send me to the correct place on the page. How can I fix this?

http://new.power-brands.de/leistungen/#Disziplinen

If you use the menu above and click on the link when you are already on the page it works...

Comment: You can link to an anchor on a different page by having your `href = 'myPage.html#someAnchorTagId'`.

Comment: It seems like this is caused by the banner at the top: the page scrolls to the referenced id before the display of the banner occurs. Any way you can change the order of events?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. It's a wordpress site...